# Can I use same mutex in different methods?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, mutex

**Situation:**  I have two methods: ***method1*** loads values of config; ***method2*** returns the values of loaded config. ***both method maybe called by different threads.***

**Issue:**  I want to use one mutex to lock/unlock two methods. so ***when method1 is locked***, when ***method2 is called it should also be locked***. I get confused when I read about mutex, when they say that i locks the region of the code until unlock is called.

**Question:**  When I lock method1, am I also locking method2?

**Expectation:** what I want to happen is method2 to be called when method1 is updating the config data that will be returned by method2.

**Sample Code:**

```
void Class::method1() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex1);
    string1 = "a value";
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1);
};

void Class::method2(string& aString) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex1);
    aString = string1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1);
    return;
};
```

Comment: You don't intend on either method calling the *other*, right? If not, a single mutex would seem adequate, latched on-entry to either method.

Comment: Is the loader designed to take an input file as a param? If not, it seems like a lazy initializer around a getter may be a better choice, that would reduce complexity if all you need is a get via method 2.

Comment: what i want to happen is method2 to be called when method1 is updating the config data that will be returned by method2.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about locking methods. You lock the *mutex*; an attempt to lock a locked mutex will block until the thread that locked it unlocks it.

Comment: "they say that i locks the region of the code until unlock is called" -- think of a mutex as a talking stick. You take the stick before speaking and hand it off when done. The time you're speaking is like the region of code.

Comment: @JimBalter I added sample code, i just want to clarify, if i lock mutex1 in method1(), when method2() is called by another thread it will wait since mutex1 is locked by method1().

Comment: Yes; that's precisely the point of mutexes and how to use them. Note, however, that you need more than that because method2 might be called before method1, in which case string1 isn't set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing producers/consumers using mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212930/implementing-producers-consumers-using-mutex)

Comment: i'm planning to initialize value in constructor so there will be no problem when method2() is called before method1(). thank you for helping me out its clear to me now.

Comment: Just a note:  method2() will leave the mutex in a locked state, since it returns before unlocking and thus pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1) is never called.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (and should) use the same mutex. Though it's more preferable to acquire it with RAII (you could use [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) if your mutex was `std::mutex` or a wrapper around `pthread_mutex_t` implementing `lock()` and `unlock()`):

```
void Class::method1() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex1);
    ...
}
```

This way not only you can place `return` statements anywhere in the code, but also you achieve exception safety (mutex will be unlocked if the method throws an exception).

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely how mutexes should be used -- to protect data from being accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. Just fix the bug in `method2` (preferably by acquiring the mutex using RAII and letting the mutex holder's destructor unlock the mutex after the return value is copied).